# Is there an easy way to convert unicode character representation to actual characters in python.

Tags: python, unicode, chinese-locale

I need to convert "disk \u6253\u5305\u5185\u5BB9" to "disk 打包内容" in python. Is there an easy way to do it

Comment: Show us the hard way and we will show you the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to convert them, they *are* those characters.  Whether they render nicely depends on your console settings.

They render just fine in Cygwin on my machine:

```
>>> print u'disk \u6253\u5305\u5185\u5BB9'
disk 打包内容
```

[image]